# Как получить название города из ширины и долготы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api

Получил широту и долготу (navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition). Можно ли получить название города?

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
              var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
              var longitude = position.coords.longitude;                 
        alert(latitude+' '+longitude);
  });

} else {
    alert("Geolocation API не поддерживается в вашем браузере");
}
```

И вообще как это выглядит?
1) узнал ширину и долготу,
2) потом эти данные вставляю в запрос к апи яндекса
3) получил город (как раз как его вывести?)

По IP не вариант.

Comment: `3) получил город (как раз как его вывести?)`  Вот это не понятно? вы хотите имя вывести города? или карту с отметкой того города вывести? или еще что небуть?

Comment: я просто хочу получить переменную с названием города. карта мне не нужна.

Comment: вообще мне последовательность интересна, с помощью кода из вопроса я получил координаты. Дальше что с ними делать?

Comment: можно узнать как вы получаете `latitude` и `longitude`?

Comment: в вопросе есть переменные `latitude` и `longitude`, через объект navigator

Comment: Делать запрос [геокодеру](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/concepts/response_structure-docpage/), затем разбирать ответ. Например, вот ответ на координаты  [30.38393345 59.94924416](https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&geocode=30.38393345%2059.94924416). Однако, надо не забывать про лимиты суточные. А чем не подходит ip? Можно было бы обойтись без запроса на геокодирование.

Comment: IP чаще всего определяет адрес провайдера, сложно найти точное АПИ которое работает с IP. Если вы знаете такой, то подскажите)

Comment: @dmitriy, а navigator.geolocation в браузере аналогично же работает, через сервисы гугла или еще какието даёт координаты. Только на мобильных девайсах есть возможность привязать gps. Как город получили? в json ответе?

Comment: Вы хотите сказать что navigator.geolocation определяет координаты по IP? В том то  и дело, что город я еще не получил

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, в любом случае, может вы знаете какие-нибудь достойные API которые определяют город по IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я решил вашу задачу с использованием yandex api maps:
Привожу пример и после него подробно расскажу что и как в нем происходит.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script charset="utf-8" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/1.1/index.xml" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>            
        // Создание обработчика для события window.onLoad
        YMaps.jQuery(function () {
            // Создание экземпляра карты и его привязка к созданному контейнеру
            var map = new YMaps.Map(YMaps.jQuery("#YMapsID")[0]),
                
                // Центр карты
                center,
                
                // Масштаб
                zoom = 10;

            // Получение информации о местоположении пользователя
            if (YMaps.location) {
                center = new YMaps.GeoPoint(YMaps.location.longitude, YMaps.location.latitude);

                if (YMaps.location.zoom) {
                    zoom = YMaps.location.zoom;
                }

                map.openBalloon(center, "Место вашего предположительного местоположения:<br/>"
                    + (YMaps.location.country || "")
                    + (YMaps.location.region ? ", " + YMaps.location.region : "")
                    + (YMaps.location.city ? ", " + YMaps.location.city : "")
                )
            }else {
                center = new YMaps.GeoPoint(37.64, 55.76);
            }

            // Установка для карты ее центра и масштаба
            map.setCenter(center, zoom);
            
            console.log(YMaps.location.country);
            console.log(YMaps.location.region);
            console.log(YMaps.location.city);
        });
        </script>
        
        <div style="width:600px;height:400px" id="YMapsID" class="YMaps YMaps-cursor-grab"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Там после инициализации YMaps у нас уже есть координаты пользователя, я решил немного расширить спектор вашего вопроса и сделал карту то же, где обозначено местоположение пользователя.

Если я правильно понял вы хотели взять координаты пользователя и узнать его местонахождение, после того как инициализирована карта у вас в свойствах YMaps есть и город и страна пользователя, которые можно взять вот так:

```
YMaps.location.country
YMaps.location.city
```

То есть если вам и не нужна будет карта то вы можете после инициализации YMaps вы просто можете взять и использовать данные под свои нужды без прорисовки карты.

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: @dmitriy Пожалуйста

Comment: Вы могли бы подсказать как не создавать карту в DOM? т.е. без карты определить местоположение

Comment: @dmitriy Извините можете подробно описать свой вопрос? создав новый? и желательно с примерами кодов, а то так долго будем обсуждать пока поймем друг друга.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/673228/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B

Comment: сделал, но суть вопроса в том, чтобы сделать тоже самое, только не рендерить карту. Если посмотреть в получившийся DOM, то карта там есть, даже если у нее стоит св-во hidden

Comment: @dmitriy я уже ответил на ваш новый вопрос.