# Как использовать геотаргетинг яндекса без карты?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, геолокация, геокодирование

Определяю местоположение пользователя так:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script charset="utf-8" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/1.1/index.xml" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>            
        // Создание обработчика для события window.onLoad
        YMaps.jQuery(function () {
            // Создание экземпляра карты и его привязка к созданному контейнеру
            var map = new YMaps.Map(YMaps.jQuery("#YMapsID")[0]),
                
                // Центр карты
                center,
                
                // Масштаб
                zoom = 10;

            // Получение информации о местоположении пользователя
            if (YMaps.location) {
                center = new YMaps.GeoPoint(YMaps.location.longitude, YMaps.location.latitude);

                if (YMaps.location.zoom) {
                    zoom = YMaps.location.zoom;
                }

                map.openBalloon(center, "Место вашего предположительного местоположения:<br/>"
                    + (YMaps.location.country || "")
                    + (YMaps.location.region ? ", " + YMaps.location.region : "")
                    + (YMaps.location.city ? ", " + YMaps.location.city : "")
                )
            }else {
                center = new YMaps.GeoPoint(37.64, 55.76);
            }

            // Установка для карты ее центра и масштаба
            map.setCenter(center, zoom);
            
            console.log(YMaps.location.country);
            console.log(YMaps.location.region);
            console.log(YMaps.location.city);
        });
        </script>
        
        <div style="width:600px;height:400px" id="YMapsID" class="YMaps YMaps-cursor-grab"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Как в данном примере не создавать карту в DOM?**
Если убираю `div`(точнее `id="YMapsID"`), то возникает ошибка `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`
Если убираю - переменную `map` - тоже ошибка.
Установить св-во hidden - тоже не хотелось бы.

Comment: а птичку поставите?)))

Comment: поставил сразу как сайт разрешил.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот и вариант когда мы только получаем данные геопозиции пользователя, и не инициализируем карту. Делаем только инициализацию `YMaps` и после этого он уже получает данные геопозиции пользователя, В примере я после этого просто вывел эти данные в `console`․

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script charset="utf-8" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/1.1/index.xml" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>            
        // Создание обработчика для события window.onLoad
        YMaps.jQuery(function () {
            // Получение информации о местоположении пользователя
            if (YMaps.location) {                               
              console.log(YMaps.location.country);
              console.log(YMaps.location.region);
              console.log(YMaps.location.city);
            }
        });
        </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```